# FIFO method using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fifo

I would like to implement the FIFO method using numpy. Specifically, I have a numpy array `STOCK` which looks like this

```py
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(1)
STOCK = numpy.random.randint(1, 9, size=(10_000, 10)) 

STOCK = array([
       [6, 4, 5, ..., 6, 8, 1],
       [1, 2, 5, ..., 2, 3, 5],
       [7, 6, 3, ..., 5, 6, 7],
       ...,
       [2, 5, 8, ..., 7, 6, 1],
       [2, 8, 7, ..., 2, 8, 4],
       [1, 2, 6, ..., 1, 1, 3]])
```

, where each row represents a different product category and each column the number of items bought at a specific date.

Now, I have second array `SOLD` which looks like this

```py
SOLD = numpy.random.randint(1, 9, size=10_000)
SOLD = array([1, 7, 3, ..., 6, 8, 5])
```

where each number represents the number of products sold per category.

**Now I want to update the `STOCK` array using the [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting) method.** Meaning, I want to *book out* the first cumulative n elements per product category. In the above case the output should be something like

```py
UPDATED_STOCK= array([
       [5, 4, 5, ..., 6, 8, 1],  # 6-1, 4, 5,     ... BOOKED OUT=1
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 2, 3, 5],  # 1-1, 2-2, 5-4, ... BOOKED OUT=7
       [4, 6, 3, ..., 5, 6, 7],  # 7-3, 6, 3,     ... BOOKED OUT=3
       ...,
       [0, 1, 8, ..., 7, 6, 1],  # 2-2, 5-4, 8,   ... BOOKED OUT=6
       [0, 2, 7, ..., 2, 8, 4],  # 2-2, 8-6, 7,   ... BOOKED OUT=8
       [0, 0, 4, ..., 1, 1, 3]]) # 1-1, 2-2, 6-2, ... BOOKED OUT=5
```

Yet, I am unsure how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I found a solution which is quite fast (similar to Mstaino's one)

```py
numpy.random.seed(1) 
STOCK = numpy.random.randint(1, 9, size=(10_000, 10))  
SOLD = numpy.random.randint(1, 9, size=10_000) 

def book_out(stock, sold):
    booking_out = numpy.minimum(stock.cumsum(axis=1), sold[:,None])
    booking_out[:,1:] -= booking_out[:,:-1] 
    stock -= booking_out
```

```py
%timeit book_out(STOCK.copy(), SOLD.copy())
> 1.13 ms ± 5.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is suitable.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

STOCK = np.random.randint(1, 9, size=(10000, 10))
SOLD = np.random.randint(1, 9, size=10000)

i = 0

while SOLD.sum() > 0:
    # The minimum between the ith column of STOCK and SOLD
    MIN = np.minimum(SOLD, STOCK[:, i])

    STOCK[:, i] -= MIN
    SOLD -= MIN

    i += 1
```

Comment: Nice, that should work! But do you think we can vectorize this problem? I think this might be a bit slow... especially if we increase the number of time steps from 10 to let's say 1,000.

Comment: Actually, it won't be influenced by the number of column of `STOCK` since the algorithm stops when `SOLD` is null.

Answer (score 0):

A more condensed way, using `cumsum`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(1,10, size=(7, 5))
out = np.random.randint(1,10, size=(7, 1))
print(x, out)

cum = x.cumsum(1)
np.diff(np.hstack((np.zeros(x.shape[0])[:,None], np.clip(cum - out, 0, cum.max()))))
```

Essentially you do a cumulative sum on the array, take out the `out`, clip at 0 and sum it back. This will reproduce a FIFO like process. It works vectorized.